# HHVM non-deterministic behaviour of the typechecker

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

I've noticed that calling hh_client is not always returning correct result. For example: I have following pieces of code:

**backend\ConvertMessage.hh:**

```
<?hh // strict

namespace ApiBackend\ConvertMessage {

    enum Status: int {
        success = 0;
        // ... error codes
    };

    // ... some other classes

};
```

**other place in project:**

```
throw new \SoapFault(
    'Server',
    \ApiBackend\ConvertMessage\Status::getNames()[$result->status]
);
```

Sometimes, after doing some changes in project I get following error message: `Could not find static method getNames in type ApiBackend\ConvertMessage\Status (Typing[4090])`

When I remove a semicolon after one of closing curly brackets, hh_client stops displaying error. But when I insert semicolon back on its place, typechecker still gives me `No errors!` message.

This is not the only file that causes this problem - it happens to all enums.

It seems to me that it is problem with some cache of either hh_client or hh_server.

Thanks in advance for helping me with solving this problem (and sorry if my english is not too good).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using an outdated version of HHVM. This problem sounds an awful lot like [this race condition](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4604), which was fixed in HHVM 3.5.0 and newer (and was backported into the 3.3.3 LTS release). Notably, 3.4.x still had the bug.

What version of HHVM are you using?

Comment: Yep, the 3.4 series is no longer supported, you should upgrade to 3.5.